# Can I transfer a Samsung Evo 850's SSD to another computer?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, computer-building, cloning

What I'd like to do is to use the SSD on the new computer I am building, but right now it has a copy of Windows on it from the old computer.

Is there a way to clone the SSD's Windows to another hard drive, then use the SSD to install a new copy of Windows on the new computer? If so, would 250 GB be enough for a new installation of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Once you've cloned the disk (I assume to continue using your current hardware) you can put the ssd in a new pc. 
Windows 10 needs 20 gb min (though your 250 gb is much more reasonable) :
https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/windows-10-specifications

When installing, you should be given the option to wipe the disk and do a fresh install. I'd do that to keep things simple, but there are also other partitioning options you could research if you want to save the current data (probably not worth it if your clone has been tested and works).

Comment: I just cloned windows from my hard drive to the new ssd, how do I clone it back to the hard drive?

Comment: Should be able to use the same cloning software